# Jenkins: sleep() isn't sleeping

Tags: jenkins

I've got a pipeline step that looks like this

```
retry(30) {
    shellOutput = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "some command")
    if (shellOutput =~ "Status: success") {
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
        commandSuccess = 1
    }
    else {
        sleep(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS')
        error("command not completed, trying again")
    }
}
```

The shell command that I'm calling prints the time when it starts so I can see from looking at Jenkins console output that it's not sleeping at all, it's running as fast as it can. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats strange. What console output do you get? Does you log contain `Sleeping for 30 sec`?

Comment: I figured it out - see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if the shell command exits non-zero then the entire rest of the block is skipped. So the if/else is never even considered. The workaround I found was to add `|| true` after the command, which always exits zero, so the if/else is no longer skipped.